# Top 10 largest private physics research centers in U.S.?

Tags: research-process, united-states, industry, physics

What are the top 10 private companies with the largest (in terms of number of researchers) R&D departments that do research in physics similar to what could be found at a Research 1 university?

For example, IBM has a Physical Sciences Department of their Research Division, located at the [Thomas J. Watson Research Center](https://www.research.ibm.com/labs/watson/index.shtml).

Comment: What's your field?

Comment: @scaaahu: physics, mathematics

Comment: There is a related [question on Math Overflow](http://mathoverflow.net/q/28526/10833) about Math.

Comment: I have been wondering the same thing about private companies that do CS theory research.

Comment: This is very much like asking "what are some schools that have good research efforts in physics or mathematics". Any answer is going to be incomplete, ephemeral, subject to opinion, subject to interpretation, subject to exactly which corner(s) of those fields you are asking about...

Comment: I am torn on this question. The answer here will likely be just a long list of private research centres or departments, which neither fits the SE model very well, nor would the answers necessarily be overly interesting.

Comment: @Geremia, I think this has ended up on hold because there are a **lot** more of these institutions than you think there are.  What is the underlying that you are trying to answer by asking this question?

Comment: @keshlam: I'm not asking which ones are "good," but just which the major ones are.

Comment: I doubt that anyone _knows_ which "the major ones" are. Businesses, unlike academia, don't publish everything they're researching. And "physics, mathematics" covers a HUGE range. What question are you really trying to get an answer to here -- which ones might hire an academic? That will depend on what problems they're trying to solve this month.

Comment: It really depends by field and what you are asking about.  There are entire *companies* just devoted to R&D.  I work at one, [BBN Technologies](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BBN_Technologies), which has about 700 employees, the vast majority of whom are active researchers. [SRI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SRI_International), out on the West coast, is similar and about three times our size.  If you count [Batelle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Battelle_Memorial_Institute), the numbers go up by an order of magnitude, but it's unclear where to draw the line, and that's not even touching biotechs.

Comment: So: what do you mean by "major"?  What counts?  Why do you want to know?  I can list off big private R&D groups whose work includes R1-level math and physics all day, but I'm not sure that I could tell you which are the biggest or whether it would actually give you the information that you are really looking for.  There's a **lot** in the US alone, and that's even before you start considering quasi-private organizations in other nations like [TNO](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Netherlands_Organisation_for_Applied_Scientific_Research) and Fraunhofer.

Comment: Echo to @jakebeal. What do you mean by _largest_? In terms of number of research staffs? In terms of money invested? Research output? Also, you need to narrow the question down to locations. North America? Europe? Asia? Or just the whole world? And, does government sponsored org count ? Is NASA one of your candidates (NASA has contrctors)? etc. Without further info, your question is too broad (I am not one of the close voters).

Comment: I just voted to re-open because you narrow it down to a reasonable extent. Now it's left to the community to decide. Good luck!